# How to update data at navigator.devicemedia without any errors

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio, web-audio-api

[image: img]

I am new to JS and I was creating a Music Amplifier. The image you see is a small snippet of what I am creating.

My HTML

```
 <label for = "noisesup">Noise Suppression</label>   
 <input type = "checkbox" id = "noisesup"class = "checker">
```

My CSS

```
.checker{
    width: 80px;
    height: 30px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: rgb(141, 103, 54);
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 0.7px solid rgb(177, 124, 51);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px;
    transition: .4s;
    
}

.checker::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: rgb(101, 70, 43);
    outline: 1px solid rgb(71, 50, 23);
    height: 29px;
    width:40px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10;
    transition: .4s;
    
    
}

.checker:checked:before{
    transition: .4s;
    transform: translateX(40px);
    
}
```

My JS

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const gaincont = document.getElementById("gain");
const echocan = document.getElementById("echo");
const noisesup = document.getElementById("noisesup");
const latency = document.getElementById("latency");

const width = canvas.width;
const height = canvas.height;

const context = new AudioContext();

function eventlistners() {

    noisesup.addEventListener("change", n=>{

        const value = n.target.value
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            audio:{
                noiseSuppression: value
            }
        })
    })
}


function getmusic() {
    return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio:{
            echoCancellation: false,
            noiseSuppression: false,
            autoGainControl: false,
            latency: 0,
        }
    })
}

async function setupcontext() {
    try{const audio = await getmusic();
        if (context.state === "suspended"){
            await context.resume();
        }
        const source = context.createMediaStreamSource(audio);
        source       
            .connect(analyser)
            .connect(context.destination);}

    catch{alert("Access Denied")}
    
}


eventlistners();

setupcontext();
```

So what I wish to do is that whenever I toggle these switches, I should be able to update them at

```
navigator.mediaDevices
```

I tried the below code but it repeatedly asks me this every time I toggle the switch: [image: img]

```
noisesup.addEventListener("change", n=>{

        const value = n.target.value
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            audio:{
                noiseSuppression: value
            }
        })
    })
```

Then I did this but now it says I need 3 parameters and only 1 found.

```
noisesup.addEventListener("change", n=>{

        const value = n.target.value
        navigator.getUserMedia({
            audio:{
                noiseSuppression: value
            }
        })
    })
```

So how do I get about this?

Comment: Can you add some of the relevant HTML ?

Comment: Have added it in my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`. The one in your first example snippet. The second example snippet is deprecated.

The issue here (from what I can see) is that `getUserMedia` is suppose to request permissions everytime it is called. So the prompt is expected.

You need to store the stream in a variable, and that variable needs to be declared outside of the event handler.

```
async function start(constraints) {
  let stream = null;

  try {
    stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
    /* use the stream */
  } catch(err) {
    /* handle the error */
  }
}
```

Once you have the stream stored in a variable, you should be able to access the tracks via `getTracks()`, and then apply contrainsts to a track from there.

- `getUserMedia`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia
- `getTracks()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream/getTracks
- `applyContraints()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/applyConstraints

In summary, don't call `getUserMedia` in an event handler.

Comment: I didn't understand it very much. What changes shall I do to the code?

Comment: I understood that I have to change the tracks and all but how to apply it to the code?

Comment: I don't have the time to rewrite all your code for you, but if you read the above docs, along with my explanation above, it should enable you to restructure your code. The key point is lifting the stream variable outside of the handler